# How to change the cursor's color to red when reaching row 90 in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, text-cursor

I have opened a buffer with some text on 100 lines.

I would like to change the color of my cursor to red when I reach the row 90?

How would such Elisp function I could put in my init file look like?

Let's say the hook should work for all modes, for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did *not* know how to do that before answering. I will tell you how I did find the solution using Emacs.

You can change the colour of the cursor by changing the `:background` attribute of the `cursor` face (as seen when using `describe-face`, or by reading the "Cursor Display" section of the Emacs manual - which is built-in and can be read from Emacs)

I am not aware of a "good" hook that could be used to do this, though. An idea could be to use `post-command-hook`, but it might be slow.

A (possibly, and probably bad, not thoroughly tested) solution:

```
(defun my/switch-cursor-color ()
  (if (< (line-number-at-pos) 90)
      (set-face-attribute 'cursor nil :background "#abcd12") ;; hex-code for your colour
    (set-face-attribute 'cursor nil :background "#1234ef")))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my/switch-cursor-color)
```

Of course, to be safe, you should probably do other checks (what happens in pdf-view-mode/doc-view-mode, etc), but this "should work".

---

How to get all this information:
Inside Emacs:

- `C-h i` opens the Info directory
- Navigate (or use `m`) to the Emacs one
- Press `i` and search for cursor, or search in the Index directly, or search with `s` the "cursor" regexp ... until you find the "Cursor Display" section. If you forgot how to do that, as usual in this kind of mode, try pressing `h`, or `?`, or `C-h m` (they don't necessarily do the same thing, but are all helping you)
- In this node, you find that

> To customize its color, change the ‘:background’ attribute
> of the face named ‘cursor’ (see Face Customization).

- Click on the "Face Customization" link to view how to do it via the "Customization Interface". To do it programmatically (*i.e.* as I did above, using the `set-face-attribute` function), repeat the steps above to view how to do it.
- You can also use the function `set-face-background`, a simple wrapper around `set-face-attribute`. To discover this function, you can (and should) *also* use Emacs: a proper completion/selection system, or the function `apropos-command`, bound to `C-h a`, with *e.g.* the search "face background", and the aforementioned function is then immediately found.
- Aaaand if you forgot how to look for help, then use `C-h C-h`. This command is shown in the tutorial, itself accessible from the menus, or from the initial buffer when starting Emacs (by default), or ... etc.

Comment: Great! It works thank you a lot. As you said, perhaps it could be too taxing for pdfs or something but that is not my primary concern right now. I will probably use it only for specifci files or file extensions. Thank you again, also for a very detailed answer.